# Check Day & Month of Current Date

Tags: vb.net, date

I need to check the day and the month. I'm using `Date.Now`.

for example:

if day =9 and month=10 then
do action

How can i do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `Day` and `Month` properties of a DateTime variable:

```
Dim currentDate As DateTime = DateTime.Now
If currentDate.Month = 10 AndAlso currentDate.Day = 9 Then
   'Do something
End If
```

Answer (score 4):

The [`Date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03ybds8y.aspx) object has a [`Day`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.day.aspx) and a [`Month`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.month.aspx) property:

```
Dim today = Date.Today
Dim day = today.Day
Dim month = today.Month

If day = 9 AndAlso month = 10 Then
    ' do something ...
End If
```

Note that i've used `Date.Today` instead of `Date.Now` since you're interested in the date part anyway.

Comment: Thank you, for providing a diff way

Answer (score 2):

Date.Now.Month and Date.Now.Day. Those are properties on the Date type.

Comment: Don't know if you even need to specify `Date.Now.Month`.  You could just do `Now.Month`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim today = Date.Now.Date
If today.Day = 9 AndAlso today.Month = 10 Then ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Date.today.day      
Date.today.month
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim today = Date.Today
    Dim day = today.day
    Dim month = today.Month
    Dim year = today.Year



    If day = 10 And Also month = 10 Then
        Label1.Text = today . Day
        Label2.Text = today . Month
        Label3.Text = Date . Today
        Label4.Text = Time Of Day
        Label5.Text = year
```

Comment: Please format the code and if needed some comments to explain to make the answer more readable.